# Properly typing a multiline string in ruby with sorbet

Tags: ruby, sorbet

I'm adopting [Sorbet](https://sorbet.org/) into a project and I can't understand how should I type the following constant:

```rb
RETRIEVE_FILE_URL_QUERY = <<~QUERY.freeze
query($input: ID!) {
  node(id: $input) {
    ... on BulkOperation {
      url
      partialDataUrl
    }
  }
}
QUERY
```

The fastest way should be

```rb
RETRIEVE_FILE_URL_QUERY = T.let(<<~QUERY.freeze
query($input: ID!) {
  node(id: $input) {
    ... on BulkOperation {
      url
      partialDataUrl
    }
  }
}
QUERY, String)
```

> this is also the quick fix I got from vscode

But this raise the error

```
escape sequence meets end of file (2001)
```

As expected, since the heredoc name can't be no more found.

So I tried

```rb
RETRIEVE_FILE_URL_QUERY = T.let(<<~QUERY.freeze
query($input: ID!) {
  node(id: $input) {
    ... on BulkOperation {
      url
      partialDataUrl
    }
  }
}
QUERY
, String)
```

But this raised another error:

```
T.untyped
unexpected token "," (2001)
```

With this, I got no clue how should I handle it.

I know that I could use the concatenation operator (`+`) but I would like to not split this string.

I'm still new to ruby so I want to ask you if there is a way to handle this.

Comment: Does `T.let(<<~QUERY.freeze,String)` work?

Comment: @engineersmnky no, it doesn't

Comment: Are you Sure? It seems to work in the [playground](https://sorbet.run/#RETRIEVE_FILE_URL_QUERY%20%3D%20T.let%28%3C%3C~QUERY.freeze%2CString%29%0Aquery%28%24input%3A%20ID!%29%20%7B%0A%20%20node%28id%3A%20%24input%29%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20...%20on%20BulkOperation%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20url%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20partialDataUrl%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%7D%0A%7D%0AQUERY)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your "fastest" way violates the syntax. The terminating token *must* be on a line by itself.

When you do this:

```rb
QUERY, String)
```

You've put in something other than the terminator token `QUERY`, so it is assumed the string keeps going.

Remember that Ruby has multiple quoting systems, and is largely indifferent to multiple lines, as in:

```rb
RETRIEVE_FILE_URL_QUERY = "
query($input: ID!) {
  node(id: $input) {
    ... on BulkOperation {
      url
      partialDataUrl
    }
  }
}
".freeze
```

Where you could also use `# frozen_string_literal: true` to do the freezing for you automatically.

Comment: While the terminating token has to be on a line by itself the opening token does not, you can even open multiple HEREDOCs on the same line (not recommended but possible). It appears that `T.let(<<~QUERY.freeze,String)` works (at least in the Sorbet playground).

Comment: @engineersmnky It gets weird when you start to work with the token declaration itself as if it's the string, but you're right, that's how it behaves.